# Merge function but instead of having multiple arrays as parameters, it takes only one two dimensional array as a parameter( array of arrays)?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, data-structures, merge

my merge method for 3 arrays as input parameter:

```
public static int[] merge3(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c) {

    int aLength = a.length;
    int bLength = b.length;
    int cLength = c.length;
    int [] d = new int[aLength+bLength+cLength];

    int i = 0;//index for a;
    int j = 0;//index for b;
    int k = 0;//index for c;
    int l = 0;//index for new sorted array l.
    for (l = 0; l < d.length; l++) {
        d[l] = i < a.length && (j >= b.length || a[i] < b[j])
                ? (k >= c.length || a[i] < c[k]
                ? a[i++]
                : c[k++])
                : (j < b.length && (k >= c.length || b[j] < c[k])
                ? b[j++]
                : c[k++]);

    }

    return d;
}
```

below is a snippet of how mergeAll method should be implemented.

```
public static int[] mergeAll(int[][] arrays) {
    return new int[] {-1};
}
```

How can a 2D array be merged into a single one dimensional Array?

Comment: Depends how you want them merged. If it’s supposed to mirror the first code it’s the same thing, but you have a variable number of arrays to merge instead of the three currently hard-coded.

Comment: when running it from the main method it can take multiple arrays as input for example.
int[] a = new int[] {1,6,11,16,21};
int[] b = new int[] {2,7,12,17,22}; int[] c = new int[] {3,8,13,18,23};
int[] d = new int[] {4,9,14,19,24};
int[] e = new int[] {5,10,15,20,25};
int[][] arrs = new int[][] {a,b,c,d,e};

Comment: first you calculate the size of the single array then you use 2 for loops to iterate the 2d array and insert the values to the new array

Answer (score -1):

Using your example input:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[] {1,6,11,16,21};
    int[] b = new int[] {2,7,12,17,22};
    int[] c = new int[] {3,8,13,18,23};
    int[] d = new int[] {4,9,14,19,24};
    int[] e = new int[] {5,10,15,20,25};
    int[][] arrs = new int[][] {a,b,c,d,e};

    int[] combined = mergeAll(arrs);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combined));
  }
  
  public static int[] mergeAll(int[][] arrays) {
    int size = 0;
    for(int[] row : arrays) {
      size = size + row.length;
    }

    int index = 0;
    int[] combined = new int[size];
    for(int[] row : arrays) {
      for(int value : row) {
        combined[index++] = value;
      }
    }
    return combined;
  }
```

Output:

```
[1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```